# Displaytag caption not working

Tags: displaytag, caption

I am using displaytag to render data, I have it working without any issues. As soon as I use display:caption I get JSP compilation error with the below message. Am I missing anything? I thougt including caption would be simple. If I remove display:caption everything works fine.

aaaaa.jsp:527:14: This tag is not recognized.
            This is the table caption

Jsp code:

This is the table caption

Setup

Displaytag1.2
Web-inf/lib
Displaytag-1.2.jar
Displaytag-export-poi-1.2.jar
Displaytag-portlet-1.2.har
Itext-1.3.jar
Itext-2.0.5.jar

WEB-INF/tlds
Displaytag.tld
Displaytag-12.tld
Displaytag-el.td

Answer (score 0):

Can you put your jsp code fragment here? It will help others to answer.
Also, you can change caption text to see if caption text has some special characters the tag doesn't support.
Lastly, make sure your `display:caption` tag is inside `display:table` tag.